# My python file will use pandas to drop a column but it wont affect the file.

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The purpose of my code is to delete a column that doesn't have a header, which Python calls "Unamed 12". In the print df command you can see that the column is dropped but when I look at my file it is still there. How can I get the code to drop the column form the file?

```
Import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
df.drop (['Unamed: 12'], axis = 1, inplace = True
print (df)
```

Comment: Check the spelling of the column, in most case it is 'Unnamed: 12'

Comment: "Unamed 12" != "Unamed: 12", and as @Vaishali both misspell the word "unnamed" (two Ns). Your code is also missing a right parenthesis, so it wouldn't run in the first place.

Comment: you're loading the csv into a pandas dataframe. If you want to change the csv you have to write the updated dataframe back into the csv. `df.to_csv(...)`

Comment: Second answer in that dupe solves your problem. If not, please edit your question to provide more detail, input, and desired output. No one can help you like this. The code you've pasted here isn't even capable of running.